# Select an expression with nhibernate queryover

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

using nHibernate QueryOver I want to select a series of values that include an aggregate expression. So the sql might be:

```
SELECT SUM(Total / (TaxRate + 1)) Totals FROM Contract Group By CustomerId
```

I can't see where (or if) this is supported. It seems odd that I can write where clauses as expressions but not define columns in the select as expressions.

Comment: HQL is your friend here! BTW you have a zero accpet rate :)

Comment: Another way is to write a view that has the calculations and map from that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I dont have your code I cant verify any of this but you can try this:

```
var dividePropertyProjection = Projections.SqlProjection(
                "SUM(Total/TaxRate+1) as Totals", new string[] {"Totals"}, new IType[] {NHibernateUtil.Decimal});  //Assuming the sum is decimal, you can change it



var list=   Session.QueryOver<Contract>().Select(Projections.Group<Contract>(x=>x.CustomerId),dividePropertyProjection).List();
```

Not sure what list will return, I am guessing it should return `CustomerId, Sum` combination.

Hope that helps

Comment: That's great! Saves me converting the entire query.